# Hyperledger Fabric: Should we use the TLS provided by Fabric or Docker?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric provides TLS for secure communication between containers [[1]](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/enable_tls.html). However this is also something that is provided out of the box by [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#encrypt-traffic-on-an-overlay-network) using the `--opt encrypted` flag. So which is the better option to choose and what is the best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Fabric in production, always use TLS. 
Fabric's public TLS settings (TLS CA certificates) are actually encoded inside the blockchain, and the nodes (peers, orderers) use them to build the CA certificate pools per channel.

If you use any third party solution, there is no way of ensuring your authentication is per channel and not globally, and this exposes you to attacks.